# Click add new row button 1st row radio button value is undefined in jquery

Tags: jquery

How to get radio button selected value - when I click new row add button at the time 1st row selected radio button value is undefined in jquery.

```
    $.each('.isexecutedcls', function (key, val) {
        var pattern_key = '';
        if (parseInt(key) > 0)
        {
            var tmp_key = parseInt(parseInt(key) + 1);
            pattern_key = '_' + tmp_key;
        }
        var is_executed_val = $('#is_executed' + pattern_key).find('input[name="IsExecuted'+ pattern_key+'"]:checked').data('val');
        console.log(is_executed_val);
    });
```

Comment: The code doesn't seem relevant to what you're asking. The question is about an undefined value when appending a new row, yet the code is an AJAX request with no event handlers...?

Comment: "*1st row is undefined*" - because you skip the first row with `if (key>0)` so your pattern_key==''.  Change the if to `if (key >= 0)`.  Remember that loop iterations start a zero https://api.jquery.com/each/ "Each time the callback runs, it is passed the current loop iteration, beginning from 0."

Comment: If your first #is_executed is `id=is_executed` rather than being `id=is_executed_1` then there's other issues and we'll need to see the HTML.

Comment: Please edit the question to add html/javascript, add with an "Edit:" if it affects existing answers (doesn't in this case)

Comment: Without the HTML that this attempts to read, this question is not answerable.